# Как передать список методу?

Tags: python, format

Чтобы вычистить всё лишнее из строки или чтобы сформировать строку приходиться делать неприятные вещи:

```
stroka.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',','').replace('!','')
stroka_sample.format(spisok[0],spisok[1],spisok[2]))
```

Как это оптимизировать?

Answer (score 1):

[str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
tr = str.maketrans('', '', '[],!')
stroka.translate(tr)
```

[Специальный синтаксис для преобразования списка в аргументы функции](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

```
stroka_sample.format(*spisok)
```